# Any simple way to get regression prediction intervals in R?

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I am working on a big data set having over 300K elements, and running some regression analysis trying to estimate a parameter called Rate using the predictor variable Distance. I have the regression equation. Now I want to get the confidence and prediction intervals. I can easily get the confidence intervals for the coefficients by the command:

```
> confint(W1500.LR1, level = 0.95)
              2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept) 666.2817393 668.0216072
Distance      0.3934499   0.3946572
```

which gives me the upper and lower bounds for the CI of the coefficients. Now I want to get the same upper and lower bounds for the Prediction Intervals. Only thing I have learnt so far is that, I can get the prediction intervals for specific values of Distance (say 200, 500, etc.) using the code:

```
predict(W1500.LR1, newdata, interval="predict")
```

This is not useful for me because I have over 300K different distance values, requiring to run this code for each of them. Any simple way to get the prediction intervals like the confint command I showed above?

Comment: The predict command will give you exactly what you want and all you have to do is run the command once. I'll mock up an example for you.

Comment: Omit the newdata argument: `predict(W1500.LR1, interval="prediction")` should do it.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you think you would ever need to run `predict` separately for each individual case for which you desire a prediction interval. Can you expand on that?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess but I assume that he is trying to get a prediction interval for the betas (so one interval for each x) which is not correct.  I think their confusion is with the use of the term confidence interval because you can have a confidence interval for the beta coefficients of the regression and you can also have a confidence interval (which is different than a prediction interval) for the predicted future values.  Once again, just a guess.

Comment: `predict(W1500.LR1, newdata=data.frame(Distance=unique(orig_data$Distance)), interval="predict")` ... ??

Answer (score 12):

Had to make up my own data but here you go

```
x = rnorm(300000)
y = jitter(3*x,1000)

fit = lm(y~x)

#Prediction intervals
pred.int =  predict(fit,interval="prediction")

#Confidence intervals
conf.int =  predict(fit,interval="confidence")

fitted.values = pred.int[,1]

pred.lower = pred.int[,2]
pred.upper = pred.int[,3]

plot(x[1:1000],y[1:1000])
lines(x[1:1000],fitted.values[1:1000],col="red",lwd=2)
lines(x[1:1000],pred.lower[1:1000],lwd=2,col="blue")
lines(x[1:1000],pred.upper[1:1000],lwd=2,col="blue")
```

[image]

So as you can see your prediction is for predicting new data values and not for constructing intervals for the beta coefficients.  So the confidence intervals you actually want would be obtained in the same fashion from conf.int.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not now that I can keep the predictions like this and then use them for plotting. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem.  Let me know if anything is unclear (code wise and theoretically).